# should I save user information in local database

Tags: android, performance

I newbie to android programming and I have question which might sound silly.
I am writing app for a shopping store, which communicate with store's website

Every user must sign in to use the app.
In sign-in process, I save information like user name, address to send products and phone number in website's database.

I have 2 questions:

1. should I also save user information in local database(sqlite), so in case user would like to change stuff, I won't need to fetch it from web server?(or fetching it every time is better approach??)
2. The app, display list(picture+description) of products the user can buy(total 12 products). 
   the list can change every 2 weeks or month. should I save the images locally and have an AsyncTask to check if something changed and only then to download the delta, or should I download them every time.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Android provides support for user accounts so it's hard to say whether you can use that or whether you need to implement a custom solution without more details. Have a look [here](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-authenticator.html) for some information on implementing authentication accounts

As for question 2, I would store the images locally as you say there are only 12. You could then have the server notify the mobile app (check out [GCM](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)) when there is an image update to pull from the server. You can also have a look at the [Volley](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) library which will assist you in retrieving and displaying images from a web server.

Comment: thanks you helped me a lot! BTW didn't know about GCM and i will defiantly read about it.

Answer (score 0):

you can store any information in sqlite and use some cache(private/public) to store images for first time store images in cache and from second time onwards load images from that cache use volley library for server calls and image cache
http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

Comment: what do you mean "store images in cache"? save in memory/temp files? or to download them to filesystem and in next app execution just to check if some pictures changed?

Answer (score 0):

for question two: no you don't need to save the pictures locally to keep your app using the minimum storage space.

Comment: From what you suggest, it means that when user open the app, its need to download all the picture again, even though some pictures didn't change.

Comment: As an end user i'd prefer viewing them every time more than saving them on my card. each solution has it's pros and cons.

Comment: This would cause the application to rely heavily on the user having a network connection. Unless your images are very large, the storage required for images of 12 products on a modern device is negligible.